# .NET Core 2.0 add service IAmazonS3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core, aws-sdk

I have follow this guide to configure my .net core application to work with AmazonS3 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-netcore.html

But when I want to add as service, I'm getting an error
Can anyone help me to understand how to solve this ?
Thanks and regards
[image]

Here is error as text: *Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0311  The type 'Amazon.S3.IAmazonS3' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAWSService(IServiceCollection, ServiceLifetime)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Amazon.S3.IAmazonS3' to 'Amazon.Runtime.IAmazonService'. AppName D:\API\AppName\Startup.cs   112 Active*

Comment: can you paste the text of the error into the question so it will be searchable?

Comment: Any idea why this is happening and how can be solved?

Comment: sounds like maybe a wrong mapping for the DI in your startup.cs

Answer (score 2):

OK, so I've found what the problem was for me. I've had aws package added as nuget package and in assemblies. Removing it from assemblies helped.